# Как правильно спарсить столбец из html страницы?

Tags: python, html, парсер

У меня имеется такая страница, из нее нужно спарсить столбец "№" и "Primaryid"
Как более грамотно можно это сделать?

Пытался через цикл, получилось криво

[image]

Так же хочу приложить "Инструменты разработчика":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[тык раз](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.ru/bs4ru.html)

[сюда тоже тык](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

[и последнее сюда](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+python&ei=2axFYcmlOI6nqtsP5eeZwA4&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+python&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgAEA1KBQg8EgEySgQIQRgAUOcNWJYUYNMVaAJwAngAgAF0iAGtA5IBAzEuM5gBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiJ9oDGlojzAhWOk2oFHeVzBugQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)

Если действительно непонятна документация и приведенные примеры, но очень хочется реализовать задуманное - необходимо указывать свои попытки, в ином случае "никто за тебя не будет это делать".

Comment: спасибо, сейчас почитаю

Answer (score 0):

Могучая панда всё сделает за тебя

```
import pandas as pd

table_MN = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota')
print(table_MN)
```